# Changing @State variable to value from UserDefaults on load not updating Picker

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to update a @State variable upon loading my app with a value stored in UserDefaults but my Picker is not updating. This is what I tried:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var selectedCanteen = 1

    init() {
        let previousSelectedCanteen = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedCanteen")
        if let exist = previousSelectedCanteen {
            self.selectedCanteen = Int(exist) ?? 1
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
       Picker(selection: $selectedCanteen, label: Text("Testing...")) {
          Text("Stuff").tag(1)
          Text("Stuff 2").tag(2)
       }
    }
}
```

I'm coming from react-native so might I might have missed some basic concepts in Swift/SwiftUI. Hope somebody can lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following approach

```
@State var selectedCanteen: Int

init() {
    let previousSelectedCanteen = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "selectedCanteen")
    var initialValue = 1
    if let exist = previousSelectedCanteen {
        initialValue = Int(exist) ?? 1
    }
    _selectedCanteen = State<Int>(initialValue: initialValue)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this approach?

Comment: `@State` does not link to owner till complete view construction, so its wrapped value cannot be changed during this time, so initial value kept (this is what you observe). I propose to initialise `@State` explicitly with desired value, read from preferences, in constructor. This is the way to give initial value for `@State` dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, I learned about the underscore syntax here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617